# How to set ToS field in IP header for a TCP connection using Golang

Tags: sockets, go, ipv4

I am trying to create a TCP server and client using Golang where I am able to set the Type of Service field in the IP header in order to prioritise different traffic flows.

The client and servers are able to communicate but I can not figure out how to set the ToS field.

I have tried using the ipv4 Golang package with the method described here: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4#NewConn

A simplified server example:

```
func main () {
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp4", "192.168.0.20:1024")
if err != nil {
    // error handling
}
defer ln.Close()
for {
    c, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        // error handling
    }
    go func(c net.Conn) {
        defer c.Close()

        if err := ipv4.NewConn(c).SetTOS(0x28); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err.Error())
        }
    }(c)
}
```

And the corresponding client (also simplified)

```
func main () {

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp4", "192.168.0.20:1024")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for {

            writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
            // Create "packet"
            Data := make([]byte, 1200)
            endLine := "\r\n"



            //Set packetLength
            length := strconv.FormatInt(int64(1200), 10)
            copy(Data[0:], length)

            //Set ID
            idString := strconv.FormatInt(int64(1), 10)
            if strings.Contains(idString, "\r") || strings.Contains(idString, "\n") || strings.Contains(idString, "\r\n") {
                fmt.Println("This is gonna result in an error in the id string.")
            }
            idbuf := []byte(idString)
            copy(Data[15:], idbuf)

            //Set timestamp
            timestamp0 := time.Now().UnixNano()
            timestampString := strconv.FormatInt(timestamp0, 10)
            if strings.Contains(timestampString, "\r") || strings.Contains(timestampString, "\n") || strings.Contains(timestampString, "\r\n") {
                fmt.Println("This is gonna result in an error in the timestamp string.")
            }
            buf := []byte(timestampString)
            copy(Data[50:], buf)

            copy(Data[int(1200)-2:], endLine)

            if len(Data) != int(1200) {
                fmt.Println("This is also gonna be an error. Length is: ", len(Data))
            }
            //Send the data and flush the writer
            writer.Write(Data)
            writer.Flush()
        }
        //time.Sleep(1*time.Nanosecond)
    }
```

I have also tried creating my own dialer with a control function that passes a syscall in order to set the socket like this:

```
    dialer := &net.Dialer{
        Timeout:       5 * time.Second,
        Deadline:      time.Time{},
        LocalAddr:     tcpAddr,
        DualStack:     false,
        FallbackDelay: 0,
        KeepAlive:     0,
        Resolver:      nil,
        Control:       highPrio,
    }

    func highPrio(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
    return c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        // set the socket options
        err := syscall.SetsockoptInt(syscall.Handle(fd), syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_TOS, 128)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("setsocketopt: ", err)
        }
    })
```

I am verifying that it does not work by inspecting the traffic with Wireshark and am using Windows 10 Pro as my OS.

Comment: You will need to Marshal the IP Header https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/ipv4/header.go to IP structure than configure the connection using it. But you will need to learn to setup a raw socket connection and than use the IP struct generated with the custom header

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was hoping to avoid using raw sockets and it seems like the ipv4 package is designed to that based on their description

"The package provides IP-level socket options that allow manipulation of IPv4 facilities." (link: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4)

I managed to circumvent the problem by dividing the connections into different applications and defining a QoS policy for each of the applications.
It is not a perfect solution but it works for me in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I am try you ToS set method at Dial() with golang 1.15.5 and its worked:

```golang
dialer := net.Dialer{
    Timeout: this.TcpWaitConnectTimeout,
}
dialer.Control = func(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
    var err error
    c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_TOS, 0x80)
    })
    return err
}

c, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", this.serverAddr)
```

[tcpdump show me right ToS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maSC5.png)